# Get ip and port from SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have Oracle 10g

```
SQL> show addressIP + PORT
```

Is it possible to show address IP + port of machine from SQL*plus?

Comment: Do you mean the IP address and port of your client, or of the server? The database itself doesn't have a port, and could be running on more than one IP (RAC, or a host with multiple IPs). The address and port you use to connect to the database are determined by the listener, not the database itself. But if you're connected you already know those, so what is the end use for this information - might help establish exactly what you're looking for and if it's available?

Answer (score 4):

```
select sys_context('userenv', 'ip_address') ip_address, port
from gv$session
where gv$session.inst_id = sys_context('userenv', 'instance')
    and gv$session.sid = sys_context('userenv', 'sid');
```